# Relationship field - {count} of type, and {total_results} of type

Tags: relationships, count

I have a relationship field which contains a number of different pieces of content.

Each piece of content has a type property.

Is there anyway I can count the number of each of the types that is included in the relationship.

For example.  3 Product related items, and 2 Showcase related items.

I need to be able to get the {total_results} of each type.

This is what I'm trying to do...

```
 {if "{related:panel_type}" == "products"}

      {if "{related:count}" == "1"}
        <ul class="p">
      {/if}
        // do stuff 
      {if "{related:count}" == "{related:total_results}"}
        </ul>
      {/if}

    {/if}

  {if "{related:panel_type}" == "showcase"}

      {if "{related:count}" == "1"}
        <ul class="s">
      {/if}
        // do stuff 
      {if "{related:count}" == "{related:total_results}"}
        </ul>
      {/if}

    {/if}
```

So at the moment {total_results} is equal to 5 so my ul is not getting closed properly.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get around this problem.

I would like to keep my markup inside the exp:channel:entries loop, and ideally use only one loop.

Any help, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faffing about with loop counters is quite unpleasant and inelegant... these are the kind of problems you run into when your data-fetching is tightly coupled to your data-output. Instead put [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/) to work. Here's how:

```
{!--  ============================================
STORE THE DATA into dynamic stash lists using context.
Avoid the temptation to put any markup here.
================================================== --}

{exp:channel:entries ...}   
    {related}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="related-items" context="{related:panel_type}"}
            {stash:the-title}{related:title}{/stash:the-title}
            {stash:a-custom-field}{related:a-custom-field}{/stash:a-custom-field}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/related}
{/exp:channel:entries}


{!--  ============================================
ASSEMBLE THE MARKUP and OUTPUT THE DATA
================================================== --}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}     

    {if {exp:stash:not_empty name="related-items" context="products"}}
        <h2>Related Products</h2>
        <ul class="p">
           {exp:stash:get_list name="related-items" context="products"}
             <li>{the-title} | {a-custom-field}</li>
           {/exp:stash:get_list}
        </ul>
    {/if}

    {if {exp:stash:not_empty name="related-items" context="showcase"}}
        <h2>Related Showcase</h2>
        <ul class="s">
           {exp:stash:get_list name="related-items" context="showcase"}
             <li>{the-title} | {a-custom-field}</li>
           {/exp:stash:get_list}
        </ul>
    {/if}

{/exp:stash:parse}
```

If you were using a separate view template for your layout you wouldn't need the final stash:parse tag, but if you're setting and getting in the same template it helps to avoid parse order issues. (Full explanation and tutorials here: http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine-stash-tutorials)

Comment: Hi James, thank you very much for your reply.  I'll take a look at stash.  Looks interesting.  I'll mark this as resolved once I've had a play. Thanks again

Comment: Just had the light bulb moment... :)... partials are belting!